# SQLContext.gerorCreate is not a value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am getting error SQLContext.gerorCreate is not a value of object org.apache.spark.SQLContext. This is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import java.io.Serializable
case class Sensor(id:String,date:String,temp:String,press:String)
object consum {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[2]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
val sc=new SparkContext(sparkConf) 
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("hello" -> 5))


def parseSensor(str:String): Sensor={
    val p=str.split(",")
    Sensor(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3))
  }
val data=lines.map(_._2).map(parseSensor)
val sqlcontext=new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlcontext.implicits._
data.foreachRDD { rdd=>



val sensedata=sqlcontext.getOrCreate(rdd.sparkContext) 
}
```

I have tried with SQLContext.getOrCreate as well but same error.

Comment: Is this a typo in the title? Could you post the complete error message, so that it's obvious that it's copied literally, and not typed?

Comment: you already have a SQLContext, why do you wan't to create another?

Comment: it's really hard to read this code because the indentation is all messed up. you'll have a better chance of getting help if you post properly formatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no such `getOrCreate` function defined for neither `SparkContext` nor `SQLContext`**.

**`getOrCreate` function is defined for `SparkSession`** instances from which `SparkSession` instances are created. And we **get `sparkContext` instance or `sqlContext` instance from the `SparkSession` instance created using `getOrCreate` method call**.

I hope the explanation is clear.

**Updated**

The explanation I did above is suitable for higher versions of spark. In [the blog](https://mapr.com/blog/real-time-streaming-data-pipelines-apache-apis-kafka-spark-streaming-and-hbase/) as the OP is referencing, the author is using spark 1.6 and [the api doc of 1.6.3](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#getOrCreate(org.apache.spark.SparkContext)) clearly states

> > Get the singleton SQLContext if it exists or create a new one using the given SparkContext

Comment: I have taken this code from some tutorial. And they have used it like this.

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: https://mapr.com/blog/real-time-streaming-data-pipelines-apache-apis-kafka-spark-streaming-and-hbase/ check this.