# Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM in eclipse

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I need to use streaming context and spark context in a single program as I am using SQLContext for which spark context is required. Here is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
//import java.io.Serializable
case class Sensor(id:String,date:String,temp:String,press:String)
object consum {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[2]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
val sc=new SparkContext(sparkConf) 
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("hello" -> 5))


def parseSensor(str:String): Sensor={
    val p=str.split(",")
    Sensor(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3))
  }
  val data=lines.map(_._2).map(parseSensor)
val sqlcontext=new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlcontext.implicits._
data.foreachRDD { rdd=>



val sensedata=SQLContext.getOrCreate(rdd.sparkContext)
rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("sensor")
val res=sqlcontext.sql("SELECT id,date,max(temp) as maximum temperature,max(press) as maximum pressure FROM Sensor GROUP BY id,date")
res.show()
}
lines.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
  }



}
```

And this the error. Can anyone tell me how to use both in a single program. I am using eclipse. Plus I have used some part of code from a tutorial, if I am using it wrong please tell me.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:82)
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:864)
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:81)
consum$.main(consum.scala:16)
```

Comment: The blog you are depending on is using 1.6 version of spark and you must be using higher version of spark. I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969564/5880706) please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the body of the constructor `new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))`, you'll be able to see that to instantiate `StreamingContext`, this constructor itself is creating an Instance of `SparkContext` through `StreamingContext.createNewSparkContext(conf)`:

```
def this(conf: SparkConf, batchDuration: Duration) = {
  this(StreamingContext.createNewSparkContext(conf), null, batchDuration)
}
```

The first thing to run anything in spark is `SparkContext`. So whether it is `StreamingContext` or `SQLContext` you are creating, you'll be needing an instance of `SparkContext` already created in the environment.

In your case, you can easily escape the error if you create the `SparkContext` before anything else and then pass this SparkContext object in the constructors of `StreamingContext` and `SQLContext`

```
val sc=new SparkContext(sparkConf) 
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
val sqlcontext=new SQLContext(sc)
```

This above code will be using the following constructor of StreamingContext:

```
def this(sparkContext: SparkContext, batchDuration: Duration) = {
  this(sparkContext, null, batchDuration)
}
```